# Can't log in to twitter with selenium: Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to log in to twitter with a bot.

```
self.browser.get('https://www.twitter.com/login') 
sleep(20)  
username_input = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input')
sleep(20)
username_input.send_keys(username)
sleep(5)
```

But I keep getting No Such Element error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input"}
```

I copied and pasted the exact Xpath and I can't figure out why it can't find the field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see `name='text'` is unique in HTML DOM. So there is no need to use XPath.

```
username_input = self.browser.find_element(By.NAME, "text")
username_input.send_keys('send username here')
```

A way better approach will be to induce `ExplicitWait`.

**Code:**

```
self.browser.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 30)
self.browser.get('https://www.twitter.com/login')

username_input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "text")))
username_input.send_keys('send username here')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

CSS selector will be:

```
input[name='text']
```

XPATH will be:

```
//input[@name='text']
```

to use them, instead of `By.NAME` please use `By.CSS_SELECTOR` or `By.XPATH`

Answer (score 0):

This works like magic for me. Because there is only one input I was sure it was the first input. Feel free to test it with inputs[1] or inputs[2] if needed.

```
inputs=self.browser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'input')
inputs[0].click()
inputs[0].send_keys('c.samanja09@gmail.com')
```